# Definition of globally uniformly asymptotically stable

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, nonlinear-system, stability-in-odes, stability-theory

In the book "Nonlinear systems" (Khalil, 3rd edition, page 150), an equilibrium is said to be globally uniformly asymptotically stable if

1. it is uniformly stable,
2. $\delta(\epsilon)$ can be chosen to satisfy $\lim_{\epsilon\to\infty}\delta(\epsilon)=\infty$,
3. for each pair of positive numbers $\eta$ and c, there is $T(\eta,c)>0$ such that
   $$||x||<\eta, \forall t\geq t_0+T(\eta,c), \forall ||x(t_0)||<c.$$

I have a question about the second condition. Why shall we need it? Is it necessary?